# Failure on logging out from the session in php

Tags: php, session

have such a logout.php algorithm. On the index page, I have integrated logout.php link with "Logout" button. When I click "logout" button, it returns to logout.php page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{   
header("Location: http://misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/");
}
?>
```

But there is a direction problem in the `header'. When I put a link, it doesn't go anywhere. But when I put a file location in the same root, it works.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the conditional statement.

Comment: But Fred, I want it to log out also from the session. I've tried your idea to check how it works, it still doesn't go to the link.

Comment: Have you got any rewrites happening? Your header's location may be a factor here.

Comment: so `header('Location: foo.php')` works, but `header('Location: http://example.com/bar.php')` doesn't?

Comment: I will try it Stilly.stack. Fred, nothing happens. The page stays at the same page.

Comment: You need to show me how you're using that link to logout then. I use that method all the time and with no problems.

Comment: `session_start(); session_destroy(); header("Location: login.php");` is what I use, no problemo.

Comment: No, Marc. Actually it was working when I was using mysql server. Now I'm using azure. So I had to change my sql statements. After changing, I couldn't manage to run it again.

Comment: Just for fun, try `header("Location: http://www.google.com/");` if that works, then you know where/what to look for.

Comment: Fred, <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="over1"></span><span class="txt1">LogOut</span></a></li> this is the way how I use it. If it will be beneficial, I can send you all the codes of the page where I call logout.php

Comment: It's ok, I don't need those codes. What you've shown me is enough. I think it may be an `.htaccess` and/or server config issue.

Comment: which modifications should I do, then, Fred?

Comment: I don't know what you have for settings in your server. That, you'll need to see if you have a redirection/mod_rewrite happening in `.htaccess` if one exists, or on the `azurewebsites.net` domain.

Comment: Btw, I don't think you have a `logout.php` file on your server. Not after trying to access http://misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/logout.php I get the following error message: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` Which may explain the issue here. Unless you're using another name for it.

Comment: no, Fred. It should be at the address; misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/website/logout.php

Comment: That's the problem then. When I clicked on `misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/website/logout.php` it brings right back to `http://misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/` you need to set your header to a different page, such as `header("Location: http://misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/login.php");` what it's doing is an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually I want it. :) But I don't know, maybe it originates from css files, but I don't think so, on the website/index.php page, it shows a problem on going back.

Comment: Your `<a href="logout.php">` page should be `<a href="/website/logout.php">`... no? Plus it's not originating from CSS, I can assure you.

Comment: I'm sorry Fred, still the same problem.

Comment: Well then, you'll need to use some type of conditional statement for your session and check if it is set, `isset` as in `if(isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){ // do something }else{ // do something else }` this has something to do with redirection of sorts, that where one or all your files using sessions are not properly set. There's not much else I can do, not without seeing full code for all pages using sessions.

Comment: Fred, I have a session.php page which is included in website/index.php page. It involves; <?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$check=$_SESSION['login_username'];
$session=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='$check' ");
$row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($session);
$login_session=$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

Comment: You say a `session.php page` page. How does that get included into the whole website?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is then. I suggest you add error reporting or something, I'm completely baffled by all this and am out of options/ideas. Try a different page location for your header. If that works, then you'll know what to look for.

Comment: Fred, session.php page is called from website/index.php page. I have also tried another address, it still doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: may it originate from css files in index page?

Comment: I have no idea at all. Try temporarily deleting the `.css` file and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location:http://misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying now fortune.

Comment: Are you setting any session variables in the relocated URL? Fortune's code would work 100% of the time.